# Github pages: How to extend base layout?

Tags: github, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

In my github pages directory, I have a folder called `_layout` in which I have a template file called `base.html`.

It contains nothing more than:

```
<p>Test 1</p>
{{ content }}
<p>Test 2</p>
```

In each of my markdown pages (`test.md`), at the top of the file I have the following:

```
---
title: TEST PAGE
layout: base
---

<p>Test Page Content</p>
```

However, when I go to serve this website and I go to `test.html`, all that appears is the contents of the test page - it does not place itself in the layout defined by `base.html`.. what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The folder should be called `_layouts`, with an `s`.